# My React JS app crashes when I realod the page using subdomain apache ubuntu server 20

Tags: reactjs, apache, ubuntu, subdomain, vite

could someone else help to me how I would configure apache/htaccess/reactapp in order to avoid the webapp crashes

My subdomain is eg. https://subdomain.example.com (it's working fine) the page loaded well if I refresh the page the page loaded well too. I think just right it is because the index.html is serving route home page.

But if I go to eg. https://subdomain.example.com/about (it's working fine as well) but here is the problem when I reload the page "Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server". all pages after the domain crashes when I refresh the page

```
my htaccess
`
```

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

```
`

Server Ubuntu server 20.04

virtual host

`
```

```
<VirtualHost IP:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-app

  <Directory /var/www/my-app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        

</VirtualHost>
```

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this one in my htaccess root folder of ReactJS app

The credits for this guy: https://putridparrot.com/blog/react-router-dom-direct-url-or-refresh-results-in-404/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```